# Creating a for loop to separate unique values into two lists

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, unique

Hello I am creating a for loop to separate the unique values into two lists.

Describing the columns:

```
print(flight_data_finalcopy['UniqueCarrier'].describe())
print(flight_data_finalcopy['Origin'].describe())
print(flight_data_finalcopy['OriginCityName'].describe())
print(flight_data_finalcopy['OriginStateName'].describe())
```

Which outputs:

```
Output:

       `count     433298
        unique        12
        top           WN
        freq      101335
        Name: UniqueCarrier, dtype: object
        count     433298
        unique       294
        top          ATL
        freq       29413
        Name: Origin, dtype: object
        count          433298
        unique            290
        top       Atlanta, GA
        freq            29413
        Name: OriginCityName, dtype: object
        count         433298
        unique            52
        top       California
        freq           54922
        Name: OriginStateName, dtype: object
```

My objective is two separate the uniquely described values into two different lists. One list should have the unique values < 55 and the rest should go to the second list. It works but the problem is everything keeps appending to one list.Is there something I am missing? Assistance would be appreciated, thanks. Here is my code:

```
dummies_columns = []
frequency_distribution_columns = []
for column in categorical_columns:
    if (flight_data[column].unique) <= 55:
        dummies_columns.append(column)
    else:
        frequency_distribution_columns.append(column)
```

Comment: Are any of the values > 55?

Comment: can you post your_df.head()?

Comment: Yes if you look at the describe section above look at  unique there are values above 55 @stark.

Comment: The columns are categorical columns (object datatypes) @VaishaliGarg incase thats what you are wondering . I am trying to extract columns with a unique value count above 55 and place it in a list

Comment: Could you print the type of `flight_data[column].unique`? It might be a string in which case you have to cast it to an int. ( 290 < "55" will return True)

Comment: i got it working . Please check my solution @stark

Comment: I got it working ! please check my solution @bouletta

Comment: i got it working . Please check my solution @VaishaliGarg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I resolved the issue. Because I am in interested in finding the total amount of unique values in a column I have to call len(). So for example i find the numerical total for a column:

```
len(flight_data_finalcopy['Origin'].unique())
```

Which outputs the total amount of unique values for that column. So the above line will output:

```
Output: 294
```

Where as not calling len() previously only gave me the array showing the individual unique values and not a numeric figure.

I haveto apply the dame concept to the if statement within my for loop.
I made the changes here:

```
dummies_columns = []
requency_distribution_columns = []


    for column in categorical_columns:
        if len(flight_data_finalcopy[column].unique()) <= 55:
            dummies_columns.append(column)
        else:
            frequency_distribution_columns.append(column)
```

This successfully loops and allocates the columns to the proper lists

```
Output: print(dummies_columns)
            ['UniqueCarrier', 'OriginStateName', 'DestStateName']

Output: print(frequency_distribution_columns)
['Origin', 'OriginCityName', 'Dest', 'DestCityName']
```

Hope this helps for future Stackers !